# Are there any benefits of using "creds, _ = google.auth.default()" to retrieve Gmail API credentials instead of the method shown in the quickstart?

Tags: python, api, authentication, gmail

In the process of learning how to use the Python Gmail API, I noticed that there are two different authentication methods shown within the documentation.

The '[Configure the sample](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/python#configure_the_sample)' code uses the following method, which also involves creating an OAuth client ID and saving a credentials.json file to your computer:

```
creds = None
# The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
# created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
# time.
if os.path.exists('token.json'):
    creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('token.json', SCOPES)
# If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
if not creds or not creds.valid:
    if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
        creds.refresh(Request())
    else:
        flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
            'credentials.json', SCOPES)
        creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
    # Save the credentials for the next run
    with open('token.json', 'w') as token:
        token.write(creds.to_json())
```

However, the [sample code for sending an email](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/sending#sending_messages) uses the following authentication code:

```
Load pre-authorized user credentials from the environment.
TODO(developer) - See https://developers.google.com/identity
for guides on implementing OAuth2 for the application.
"""
creds, _ = google.auth.default()
```

I wasn't able to get the latter method to work, so in order to send an email, I replaced the `creds, _ = google.auth.default()` script with the authentication script used in the 'Configure this sample' code. However, are there any advantages to using the method shown in the email sending script(aside from its brevity)? I'm also trying to figure out why two different methods are being shown. (Perhaps one is newer and Google is still in the process of updating the code.)